# Service not starting

Tags: android

Probably an easy question for you guys, but its my first attempt at creating a service that should run in the background when my app closes. My problem is: The service doesnt start when I click on my "start service" button. I don't see any of the toast, and nothing in the logcat (no errors either). Thanks in advance!

**Service class**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

}
}
```

**My main activity**

```
public void startServiceClick(View v){

    Log.d("foo", "onClick: starting srvice");
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

public void stopServiceClick(View v){

    Log.d("foo", "onClick: stopping srvice");
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

**Manifest xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="se.johanberntsson.main"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/maps1"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LongitudeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DebugActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".GoogleMapsActivity" />

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you tried context.startService ?

is startingService log is gettting generated?

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi Tried it now, without success. And yes, i get the "onclick, starting service" in the log. But nothing from the service.. :/

Comment: i think The answer posted can solve your problem. if not post your complete code of activity, will try on my setup..

Comment: @Ankit I dont see a posted answer. I believe is was deleted. But i tried it without noticing any difference. Are you sure you want to see the complete activity? There is nothing else in there that has anything to do with the service. And the click events in it works fine.

Comment: let me try it.. will revert asap. can you try following this suggestion >>
"should call super in each function like super.onCreate();"

Comment: @Ankit Yea ive tried that. Here is the code that ive based my test on: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html It seems to be working when i run that project. But my code above doesnt work. What can possibly be different?

Comment: @Johan : see my answer and try it

Comment: i HAVE TRIED AND IT IS WORKING FINE FOR ME.. ADD YOUR EMAIL ID SO CAN SEND YOU MY TEST APP WHICH IS WORKING FOR ME!

Comment: @Ankit Thanks, but the link ive prvided also works for me. I just cant figure out whats different in my app...

Comment: please provide your complete manifest

Comment: @Johan : your manifast is f9 plz add Activity compelete code from which you are starting service\

Comment: Thanks and service package should be same as "se.johanberntsson.main"

Comment: @DheereshSingh I was just going to ask you about that. Because its in a package called `se.johanberntsson.servies`. Is that the problem?

Comment: yes sir you got that finaly ............:)

Comment: @DheereshSingh hehe :) but how to solve it?

Comment: give the full path of service in case it is differnt then your manifest package structure as that has main

Comment: try <service android:enabled="true" android:name="se.johanberntsson.servies.MyService" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this is suggestion as all else looking fine
```

should call super in each function like `super.onCreate();`

as may be possible service is already started and try to stop and start again and check it toast appears ....

try

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="se.johanberntsson.servies.MyService" />
```

Comment: No luck... are you sure its needed? http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

Comment: this is suggestion as all else looking fine

Comment: please provide your complete manifest and package of service class to confirm them  are same........

Comment: Yep! But a followup question: Can this service be started more than once? Or will there always be one instance even though i press "start" multiple times?

Comment: startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));  if the service isn't started, it will start it and then run it. If the service is started, it will just run it

Comment: in 2nd time calling startservice or running serve you just get call on onStartCommand( ....http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)

Answer (score 1):

You may have already figured this out. In your code you override several native functions so you could add a toast and a catlog entry. Don't forget to add super.{whatever function you are calling}. What that does is it tells the android device to do whatever the function would have done had the function not been overrided, then do the extra stuff. In your case, if you call your oncreate function, it then the computer will make the toast and add a catlog entry, but it will not create the service.

```
@Override    //forget about doing whatever onCreate usually does.
        public void onCreate() {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//toast
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");//Add message to cat- log
            //note: Service not created because function was overrided
        }
```

however, if you add super.onCreate, the phone will create the service, then it will do what you tell it to do.

```
@Override    //forget about doing whatever onCreate usually does.
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); // do whatever onCreate usually does. Then do whatever is after me.
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//toast
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");//Add message to cat- log

    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I added your service into my code and it is working fine for me. please see below code and match with yours.

Activity >>

```
 public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void startServiceClick(View v){

    Log.d("foo", "onClick: starting srvice");
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

public void stopServiceClick(View v){

    Log.d("foo", "onClick: stopping srvice");
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startServiceClick(v);   

}
```

Manifest File >>

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />

</application>
```

Comment: Yea i matches. Except i dont use onclicklistener. Just the `onClick` attribute in the xml. But the click gets logged so i guess thats not the problem

Comment: oh ok.. try adding onclicklistener then,., Android is not that matured yet... may be something silly happening with your code.

Comment: I think the problem might be that my service is in a different package called `se.johanberntsson.services`?